How to make the AxisLabel move in a 3D plot
I have a question related to the 3DPlot Labels.
I have this way to make a plot and I will want the plot to have rearranging labels when I rotate the plot around to maybe get a better view of it:
data6 = ParallelTable[
   Re[d[1, 1, 0.2, q, T]] // Re, {T, 0.1, 2, 0.1}, {q, 0.01, 0.4, 
    0.025}];
p0 = ListPlot3D[0 data6, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   DataRange -> {{0, 0.4}, {0, 2}}, PlotRange -> All];
p1 = ListPlot3D[data6, DataRange -> {{0, 0.4}, {0, 2}}, 
   PlotRange -> All, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", 
   LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 10, Darker[Gray], Bold}, 
   ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
   AxesLabel -> {q, T, Subscript[\[ScriptCapitalD], 2]}];


Here is a picture of the graphs that I have which have the labels in a way that is not clearly visible if I want to see the plot better. To be more precise, I want the AxisLabel of q to be in the front instead of the back when I rotate the Plot to have this orientation.


For static usage you can look up AxesEdge. For dynamic use, you will have to wait for an answer.

One possibility.
